# Appending to an argument list in an Exec task

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

Assume I want to add specific args to the beginning of the arg list for a particular case, and still include the common list of args in both cases like so:

```
if (conditional) {
    executable foo
}
else {
    executable bar
    args ['arg1', 'arg2']
}

args = ['other', 'common', 'args']
```

This complains about `> Cannot cast object 'arg1' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'int'`

Im trying to exercise one of the public apis for the exec task:

```
public DefaultExecHandleBuilder args(Object... args) {
    if (args == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("args == null!");
    }
    this.arguments.addAll(Arrays.asList(args));
    return this;
}

public DefaultExecHandleBuilder args(Iterable<?> args) {
    GUtil.addToCollection(arguments, args);
    return this;
}
```

Defined here: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/process/internal/DefaultExecHandleBuilder.java

documented here: https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html

I realize I could create a `List<String>` and build that to populate `args` with but I feel like Im overlooking an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

My syntax around args was incorrect.

Using

```
args 'arg1, 'arg2'
```

followed latter by

```
args 'rest', 'of', 'the', 'args'
```

worked by appending as expected